# out of memory exception in compress large files using io.compression

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

i am trying to not exceeded memory max size so i have to check every time if It greater than Max Memory Size Then i flush it into zip file Stream . The Problem Here it replace memory stream with existence one in file stream ,Or Is there Any way To Do the Same Rquired with Another Way ( But With Out Using Any DLL Lib)

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
   FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(sbZipFolderName.ToString(),FileMode.Create);
   foreach (FileInfo flInfo in ListfileFolderPaths)
    {
      using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true))          
      archive.CreateEntryFromFile(flInfo.FullName, slastFolderName + "/" + flInfo.DirectoryName.Replace(new DirectoryInfo(sFolderPath.ToString()).FullName, "") + "/" + flInfo.Name);
      if (memoryStream.Length > MaxSize)
      {
    using (fileStream = new FileStream(sFolderPath + "/" + slastFolderName + ".zip",     FileMode.Create))
         {
             memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
             memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
             memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

           }
      }
   }
   if ((memoryStream != null) && (memoryStream.Length > 0))
      memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
```

Comment: Why use a `MemoryStream` at all?  Just open your `ZipArchive` on the `FileStream`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, is There any example for how  to to do this

Comment: There's not much to give - `new ZipArchive(fileStream, ...` and delete all of your code relating to `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the`Gzip` archive to compress a file.

This is the compression:

```
public static byte[] Compress(byte[] raw)
{
using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(memory,
    CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    {
    gzip.Write(raw, 0, raw.Length);
    }
    return memory.ToArray();
   }
  }
}
```

And this to decompression :

```
 static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip)
{
// Create a GZIP stream with decompression mode.
// ... Then create a buffer and write into while reading from the GZIP stream.
using (GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip), CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    const int size = 4096;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
        if (count > 0)
        {
        memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }
    while (count > 0);
    return memory.ToArray();
    }
}
}
```

}

Tell me if it worked.

Goodluck.